# Error in VS code while importing pandas for python

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

So I have installed pandas via cmd. But when I tried importing it in the VS code, some unrecognizable error has occurred. I installed the numpy using the same procedure and it worked all right as I performed various codes using that. So I'm not sure what exactly this error means. Some of the keywords like genfromtxt, delimiter etc were used in the previous file that I made using numpy.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
ds= pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
print(ds)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\pyCodes\pract_26.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pandas. .core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
  File "C:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.categorical import Categorical
  File "C:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\categorical.py", line 3, in <module>
    from csv import QUOTE NONNUMERIC
  File "c:\Users\Pranami Gajjar\pyCodes\csv.py", line 2, in <module> 
    data= genfromtxt("Python.csv', delimeter=',, skip_header=1)
TypeError: genfromtxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimeter'
```

Comment: You misspelled the keyword argument `delimiter`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), esepecially the part which talks about not posting images of code (if the issues are addressed, I'll be happy to remove downvote).

Comment: Post code and error as text, not a link. We want questions to be as self contained (and internet search frriendly) as possible.

Comment: yeah, as already quoted in the comment above...you have misspelled the delimiter.

Comment: The error has been solved as someone suggested me to change the name of one file that was over shadowing my code. Thank you guys :) And I will make sure to post code and error as a text next time :)

Comment: Go ahead and update this question with the text. Maybe somebody's internet search will bring this question up and a problem will be solved.

Comment: Something went wrong with that paste. You should be able to paste the code, select it, then press the `{}` to make it a code block. All that does is indent the code 4 spaces, which stackoverlow's markdown uses to change highlighting.